# Visual Studio 2019 Professional не видит установленный ASP.NET .NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

На машине x64 Windows 7 установил MS VS 2019 Professional, вместе установил и "ASP.NET.NET Framework", но в система его нет, а доступен лишь **ASP.NET Core**. Интересно, что на другой машине x86 **ASP.NET.NET Framework** отлично встал и доступен. Как добавить данный шаблон? Дело в обновлениях Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Очень краткое описание того, что делали. "Установил VS2019" - а какие при этом ставили галки в инсталляторе?

Шаблоны предыдущих версий ставятся так.

Сначала выбираем группу "ASP.NET и разработка веб-приложений":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом смотрим вправо и выбираем конкретно какие компоненты нам нужны. По умолчанию "Дополнительные шаблоны проектов (предыдущие версии)" выключены, поставьте чекбокс:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А потому повторно запустите Visual Studio Installer и доустановите нужные компоненты.

Также вы можете перейти в раздел "Отдельные компоненты" и включить "ASP.NET и средства разработки" и совсем уж древний MVC 4:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Спасибо за ответ, данные галочки ставил. Вообще установил все галочки, чтобы уж наверняка. Интересно, что изначально вообще не запускался инсталлятор студии, установил обновление KB3004394 - запустился.