# Как настроить маршрутизацию в пустом шаблоне?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Изучаю Фриман А. - ASP.NET Core MVC 2 с примерами на C# для профессионалов
Там показано как настроить шаблон MVC из пустого проекта. Но у меня не получается. Вылетает ошибка.
Вот код ошибки:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код файла Program.cs

```
namespace Razor
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Код Startup.cs

```
namespace Razor
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            //app.UseRouting();

            //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            // {
            // endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            // {
            // await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            // });
            //});
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
}
```

Дело в том что если я копирую код этих файлов из архива с примерами из книги то происходит тоже самое.
Тут[ссылка на репозиторий с проектом](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-mvc-2/tree/master/05%20-%20Working%20with%20Razor/Razor/Razor) Если я полностью весь копирую то работает.
Собственно вопрос как правильно настроить проект?

Comment: А вы какой проект создаёте? Часом не core 3.x? А то [в 3.0 появился Endpoint routing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-3.0?view=aspnetcore-3.1), очень [похоже](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#routing-basics) на ошибку, которую вы показываете. Лучше приведите код ошибки текстом -- глаза ломать неохота, разглядывая что там мелко написано. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1203864/213987

Comment: Да вы правы, я создавал проект на 5.0

Comment: Тогда давайте так. Либо вам надо [доставить компоненты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1202456/213987) от 2.х (они объявлены как неподдерживаемые, кажется даже 2.1 уже всё), либо вам скорректировать проект (см. вопрос-дубликат) и желательно почитать все what'snew от 2 до 5, чтобы иметь представление, что поменялось. Ну или может Фримен уже новую книжку выпустил по третьей/пятой версии - тогда возьмите более свежую.